# タブの中のボタンを横並びにしたい

Tags: html, css

タブの中にあるボタンを横並びにして見やすくしたいです
flexとか、display: inline-blockとかやってみたのですができません
ちなみに、余白はバラバラですが大丈夫です
具体的にどうしたらよいのかを教えていただきたいです

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  </head>
 <body>
<font face: "Zen Maru Gothic,M PLUS Rounded 1c,Rounded M+,UD デジタル 教科書体 NK-R>
<div class="relative">
  <img src="C:\Users\tomoking\Documents\days_with_study_rogo_kanse-removebg-preview.png" class="absolute" alt="ロゴ">
  <img src="C:\Users\tomoking\Documents\benkyo kanse nami daikirei.png" alt="勉強の画像">
</div>
<br>
<div class="tabs">
  <input id="all" type="radio" name="tab_item" checked>
  <label class="tab_item" for="all">小学生</label>
  <input id="programming" type="radio" name="tab_item">
  <label class="tab_item" for="programming">中学生</label>
  <input id="design" type="radio" name="tab_item">
  <label class="tab_item" for="design">高校生</label>
  <div class="tab_content" id="all_content">
    <div class="tab_content_description">
       <p class="c-txtsp">
　　　　　<div class="btn-wrap"><a class="btn btn-border-shadow5">小1</a></div>
    　　　<div class="btn-wrap"><a class="btn btn-border-shadow6">小2</a></div>
    　　　<div class="btn-wrap"><a class="btn btn-border-shadow7">小3</a></div>
    　　　<div class="btn-wrap"><a class="btn btn-border-shadow8">小4</a></div>
    　　　<div class="btn-wrap"><a class="btn btn-border-shadow9">小5</a></div>
    　　　<div class="btn-wrap"><a class="btn btn-border-shadow10">小6</a></div>
　　　　</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<p style="text-align: center;" class="waku">
  <img src="https://www.illust-pocket.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/monochrome_kadomaru_frame_5602.jpg">
</p>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<h1>Days　with studyについて</h1>
<h2>
　　・完全無料
<br>
　　・皆さんが勉強の支えになるようなサイトを作ろうと思います
<br>
　　・少しずつ改良を重ねていきます
</h2>
   </font>
 </body>
</html>
```

css

```
@charset "utf-8";

body {
  background-image: url("C:\Users\tomoking\Documents\benkyou kanse.png");
  background-size: cover;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.relative {
  position: relative;
}
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 900px;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

/* 背景用*/
body {
  padding: -5px;
}

.btn,
a.btn,
button.btn {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.5;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem 4rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  color: #212529;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  margin: 10px 20px 30px 40px; /* 外側の時計回りの余白 */
  display: flex;
}

a.btn-border-shadow5 {
  padding: calc(1.5rem - 12px) 3rem 1.5rem;

  background: #ffff00;
}

a.btn-border-shadow5:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: -6px;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  content: "";
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;

  border: 3px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

a.btn-border-shadow5:hover {
  padding: calc(1.5rem - 6px) 3rem;
}

a.btn-border-shadow5:hover:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

/* 背景用*/
body {
  padding: -5px;
}

.btn,
a.btn,
button.btn {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.5;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem 4rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  color: #212529;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  margin: 10px 20px 30px 40px; /* 外側の時計回りの余白 */
  display: flex;
}

a.btn-border-shadow6 {
  padding: calc(1.5rem - 12px) 3rem 1.5rem;

  background: #ff9933;
}

a.btn-border-shadow6:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: -6px;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  content: "";
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;

  border: 3px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

a.btn-border-shadow6:hover {
  padding: calc(1.5rem - 6px) 3rem;
}

a.btn-border-shadow6:hover:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

/* 背景用*/
body {
  padding: -5px;
}

.btn,
a.btn,
button.btn {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.5;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem 4rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  color: #212529;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  margin: 10px 20px 30px 40px; /* 外側の時計回りの余白 */
}

a.btn-border-shadow7 {
  padding: calc(1.5rem - 12px) 3rem 1.5rem;

  background: #ff5500;
}

a.btn-border-shadow7:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: -6px;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  content: "";
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;

  border: 3px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

a.btn-border-shadow7:hover {
  padding: calc(1.5rem - 6px) 3rem;
}

a.btn-border-shadow7:hover:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

/* 背景用*/
body {
  padding: -5px;
}

.btn,
a.btn,
button.btn {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.5;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem 4rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  color: #212529;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  margin: 10px 20px 30px 40px; /* 外側の時計回りの余白 */
}

a.btn-border-shadow8 {
  padding: calc(1.5rem - 12px) 3rem 1.5rem;

  background: #ff3399;
}

a.btn-border-shadow8:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: -6px;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  content: "";
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;

  border: 3px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

a.btn-border-shadow8:hover {
  padding: calc(1.5rem - 6px) 3rem;
}

a.btn-border-shadow8:hover:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

/* 背景用*/
body {
  padding: -5px;
}

.btn,
a.btn,
button.btn {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.5;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem 4rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  color: #212529;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  margin: 10px 20px 30px 40px; /* 外側の時計回りの余白 */
}

a.btn-border-shadow9 {
  padding: calc(1.5rem - 12px) 3rem 1.5rem;

  background: #ff00ff;
}

a.btn-border-shadow9:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: -6px;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  content: "";
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;

  border: 3px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

a.btn-border-shadow9:hover {
  padding: calc(1.5rem - 6px) 3rem;
}

a.btn-border-shadow9:hover:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

/* 背景用*/
body {
  padding: -5px;
}

.btn,
a.btn,
button.btn {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.5;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem 4rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  color: #212529;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  margin: 10px 20px 30px 40px; /* 外側の時計回りの余白 */
}

a.btn-border-shadow10 {
  padding: calc(1.5rem - 12px) 3rem 1.5rem;

  background: #9966ff;
}

a.btn-border-shadow10:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: -6px;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  content: "";
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;

  border: 3px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

a.btn-border-shadow10:hover {
  padding: calc(1.5rem - 6px) 3rem;
}

a.btn-border-shadow10:hover:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

/*タブ切り替え全体のスタイル*/
.tabs {
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;}

/*タブのスタイル*/
.tab_item {
  width: calc(100%/3);
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #5ab4bd;
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #565656;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.tab_item:hover {
  opacity: 0.75;
}

/*ラジオボタンを全て消す*/
input[name="tab_item"] {
  display: none;
}

/*タブ切り替えの中身のスタイル*/
.tab_content {
  display: none;
  padding: 40px 40px 0;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/*選択されているタブのコンテンツのみを表示*/
#all:checked ~ #all_content,
#programming:checked ~ #programming_content,
#design:checked ~ #design_content {
  display: block;
}

/*選択されているタブのスタイルを変える*/
.tabs input:checked + .tab_item {
  background-color: #5ab4bd;
  color: #fff;
}

p.waku img {
  width: 67%;
  height: 67%;
]
```

Answer (score 0):

とりあえず

```
p.c-txtsp { display: flex; }
.btn-wrap { display: inline-block; }
```

あと `p.waku img` の最後が `}` ではなく `]` になっていますので修正してください。

Answer (score 0):

試しに書いてみました。
cssのボタンの設定が重複していたので1つにまとめました。（htmlのdivのclassの設定。）
cssのボタンのdisplayの設定をinline-blockにしました。

```css
@charset "utf-8";

body {
  background-image: url("C:\Users\tomoking\Documents\benkyou kanse.png");
  background-size: cover;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: padding;
  box-sizing: padding;
}

html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

/* 背景用*/
body {
  padding: -5px;
}

.btn,
a.btn,
button.btn {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.5;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem 4rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  color: #212529;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  margin: 10px 20px 30px 40px; /* 外側の時計回りの余白 */
}

a.btn-border-shadow5 {
  padding: calc(1.5rem - 12px) 3rem 1.5rem;

  background: #ffff00;
}

a.btn-border-shadow5:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: -6px;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  content: "";
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;

  border: 3px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

a.btn-border-shadow5:hover {
  padding: calc(1.5rem - 6px) 3rem;
}

a.btn-border-shadow5:hover:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

a.btn-border-shadow6 {
  padding: calc(1.5rem - 12px) 3rem 1.5rem;

  background: #ff9933;
}

a.btn-border-shadow6:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: -6px;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  content: "";
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;

  border: 3px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

a.btn-border-shadow6:hover {
  padding: calc(1.5rem - 6px) 3rem;
}

a.btn-border-shadow6:hover:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

a.btn-border-shadow7 {
  padding: calc(1.5rem - 12px) 3rem 1.5rem;

  background: #ff5500;
}

a.btn-border-shadow7:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: -6px;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  content: "";
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;

  border: 3px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

a.btn-border-shadow7:hover {
  padding: calc(1.5rem - 6px) 3rem;
}

a.btn-border-shadow7:hover:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

a.btn-border-shadow8 {
  padding: calc(1.5rem - 12px) 3rem 1.5rem;

  background: #ff3399;
}

a.btn-border-shadow8:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: -6px;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  content: "";
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;

  border: 3px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

a.btn-border-shadow8:hover {
  padding: calc(1.5rem - 6px) 3rem;
}

a.btn-border-shadow8:hover:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

a.btn-border-shadow9 {
  padding: calc(1.5rem - 12px) 3rem 1.5rem;

  background: #ff00ff;
}

a.btn-border-shadow9:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: -6px;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  content: "";
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;

  border: 3px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

a.btn-border-shadow9:hover {
  padding: calc(1.5rem - 6px) 3rem;
}

a.btn-border-shadow9:hover:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}a.btn-border-shadow10 {
  padding: calc(1.5rem - 12px) 3rem 1.5rem;

  background: #9966ff;
}

a.btn-border-shadow10:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: -6px;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  content: "";
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;

  border: 3px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

a.btn-border-shadow10:hover {
  padding: calc(1.5rem - 6px) 3rem;
}

a.btn-border-shadow10:hover:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

/*タブ切り替え全体のスタイル*/
.tabs {
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;}

/*タブのスタイル*/
.tab_item {
  width: calc(100%/3);
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #5ab4bd;
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #565656;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.tab_item:hover {
  opacity: 0.75;
}

/*ラジオボタンを全て消す*/
input[name="tab_item"] {
  display: none;
}

/*タブ切り替えの中身のスタイル*/
.tab_content {
  display: none;
  padding: 40px 40px 0;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/*選択されているタブのコンテンツのみを表示*/
#all:checked ~ #all_content,
#programming:checked ~ #programming_content,
#design:checked ~ #design_content {
  display: block;
}

/*選択されているタブのスタイルを変える*/
.tabs input:checked + .tab_item {
  background-color: #5ab4bd;
  color: #fff;
}

p.waku img {
  width: 67%;
  height: 67%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="tab.css">
  </head>
 <body>
<font face: "Zen Maru Gothic,M PLUS Rounded 1c,Rounded M+,UD デジタル 教科書体 NK-R>
<br>
<div class="tabs">
  <input id="all" type="radio" name="tab_item" checked>
  <label class="tab_item" for="all">小学生</label>
  <input id="programming" type="radio" name="tab_item">
  <label class="tab_item" for="programming">中学生</label>
  <input id="design" type="radio" name="tab_item">
  <label class="tab_item" for="design">高校生</label>
  <div class="tab_content" id="all_content">
    <div class="tab_content_description">
       <p class="c-txtsp">
　　　　　<div class="btn btn-wrap"><a class="btn btn-border-shadow5">小1</a></div>
    　　　<div class="btn btn-wrap"><a class="btn btn-border-shadow6">小2</a></div>
    　　　<div class="btn btn-wrap"><a class="btn btn-border-shadow7">小3</a></div>
    　　　<div class="btn btn-wrap"><a class="btn btn-border-shadow8">小4</a></div>
    　　　<div class="btn btn-wrap"><a class="btn btn-border-shadow9">小5</a></div>
    　　　<div class="btn btn-wrap"><a class="btn btn-border-shadow10">小6</a></div>
　　　　</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
   </font>
 </body>
</html>
```